# How can I find content type of file when mimetype is application/octetstream

Tags: java, php, phantomjs

I download a file from a URL such as "www.test.com/gfgfggg".

When I ask content type of the file I get application/octetstream.
but when I open that file I see that it's a js or css file.

does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a filename is provided you could check the extension.
Look for a Content-Disposition header like:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.js`

If this is not the case you have to look into the content to determine the type.

Comment: those files have no extension.Can you give an example?

Comment: If you are not afraid of third party libraries you could use a css parser like http://cssparser.sourceforge.net, but this might be overkill.

Comment: Found java.net.URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream, but never tried it.

Comment: URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream returnt null